Python Safelist.Numbers sample
I'm trying to add phone numbers to the safelist, but whatever I try I get exception 'Client' object has no attribute 'Safelist'. Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

The attribute probably belongs to a different class, or you're supposed to use a method to add it rather than referencing the attribute directly. Please post a [mre] and also a link to the API library you're using.

The documentation contains this example: const safelist = await client.verify.v2.safelist.create({phoneNumber: "+18001234567",});

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example We have no idea what your code looks like
